# Jquery validation, stop execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem here, i need some help
My form looks like
[image]

Requirement:
If the button is clicked, i want NOT to save record fields if one of them is greater than 100
I tried this code

```
$('.accept').click(function() {
$(this).parentsUntil('div.record').find('[name^="marks"]').each(function() {
var subjectID = $(this).attr('id');
var marks       = $(this).val();

// check value
if(marks > 100)  {
alert("error");
return false;
}
// save marks of this subject
// code to insert record into database table
});

return false;
});
```

If maybe the user fills as, Physics = 83, Maths = 89, Biology = 102, English = 94
then my code inserts the first two subjects into the database, the third stops and returns false

But I want my program NOT to insert any marks if any of the subjects is greater than 100

Anyone knows what is wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that you are running `code to insert record into database table` in the `each` loop - well, of course time travels in one directions, you can't rewind after you've found a problem and say "oh, no, don't perform the previous iterations"

easiest solution is to validate the WHOLE form, and then send data to the database

```
$('.accept').click(function() {
    const marks = $(this).parentsUntil('div.record').find('[name^="marks"]');
    let valid = true;
    marks.each(function() {
        var marks = $(this).val();
        if (marks > 100) {
            alert("error");
            valid = false;
            return false; // I gather this terminates the each loop? I don't know jQuery at all
        }
    }
    if (valid) {
        marks.each(function() {
            var subjectID = $(this).attr('id');
            var marks = $(this).val();

            // save marks of this subject
            // code to insert record into database table
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why not @MohamudNeeri

Comment: return false; doesn't stop the execution

Comment: This will proceed to send to database only if all inputs are valid. Otherwise nothing will be sent to the database

Comment: Which return false are you referring to? Are you saying this code still sends to the database with scores over 100? If so, you clearly copied it wrong

Comment: I typed var valid = true, and in the if block, i again typed var valid = false

Comment: I just realised, that last comment is what you did wrong :p